# Use of #pragma alias in c++

Tags: c++, pragma

I would like to know what does the following piece of code do, when a user predefined macro `__FLOATP__` is available

```
#ifdef __FLOATP__
#pragma alias   atanl  = atanf
#pragma alias   atan           = atanf
#endif
```

So does the piece of code compile usages the of atanl and atan to atanf, when the macro `__FLOATP__` is available?

Comment: Pragmas are compiler-dependent. Which compiler (and what version of it) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The `#pragma` directive is defined by the ANSI C standard for implementing directives that provide the compiler with various instructions. The presence of certain `#pragma` directives depends on the compiler.

In this case, as you correctly noted, `#pragma alias` acts when defining the `__FLOATP__` macro. The `#pragma alias` indicates the linker that two identifier names are equivalent. I found this information here: [#pragma alias](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Pragma_alias).